# VSFTP - How to chroot

Tags: linux, chroot

I installed `vsftpd-2.2.2-12.el6_5.1.x86_64` on `Centos 6.4 64 bit`, my users use FTP over TLS to access to FTP server. I have 2 users:

```
user1:x:504:504::/home/user1:/bin/bash
user2:x:505:505::/home/user2:/bin/bash
```

Now, after user1 login to ftp server, he stands at `/home` , he can see 2 directory : user1 and user2 , he can only access to "user1" directory, cannot access to "user2" directory. The same with user2. This is my configuration

```
/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
#passwd_chroot_enable=YES 
local_root=/home
#user_sub_token=$USER

/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
user1
user2
```

I want to restrict user to their home directory, users cannot navigate up the directory tree. I changed configuration:

```
/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
chroot_local_user=NO
chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
passwd_chroot_enable=YES
local_root=/home
#user_sub_token=$USER
```

But it's not working, users still stand at `/home` after login.

Answer (score 2):

Change according to following steps

```
chroot_local_user=YES
local_root=/ftphome/$USER
user_sub_token=$USER
```

Create directory and setting up permission :

```
mkdir -p /ftphome/{test,user1,user2}

chmod 770 -R /ftphome
chown -R ftp. /ftphome
usermod -G ftp test
```

After restarting `vsftpd` and test your setup.